# Windows length matrix to vector, extract data

Tags: python, pandas

I have difficulties to understand the following questions, can someone help me to emphasize a bit?

You will extract data for the window length n (rows), and turn the data from a matrix (2D) form into a vector (1D) form of the size (i.e. number of rows * number of columns).
-Create a function that return a 1d vector (array, tuple) of n window length from raw data
-Create a new data frame where you store the vector as a new row (see lecture notes)

Comment: Please show your sample code. You can try to flatten the numpy array and pass it to a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a sliding window of a matrix, we get always a another matrix which frame of columns * window length, just need to flatten it